# Swift: Dynamic UIView that pushes UIViews below it after a resize

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiview

What I am trying to is emulate the effect of the Jquery .slideDown() effect in Swift for an iOS app.

-I need a UIView to auto-resize based on the length of the text in it.

-The UIView needs to push other UIViews below it down.

-There needs to be a button above the UIView or on it then when tapped will cause a "Slide down" (Showing the extra text and expanding the fit the text). After re-tapping the button the UIView will resize and the text will be hidden.

Below is a GIF of the Jquery .slideDown() effect I would like to mimic in Swift.

Is this possible? Do I need to import a library?

[image: GIF of the Jquery version]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is this possible?

Yes this is possible using autolayout. [Here](https://www.raywenderlich.com/115440/auto-layout-tutorial-in-ios-9-part-1-getting-started-2) is a great tutorial on how to get started with autolayout. [Here](http://useyourloaf.com/blog/animating-autolayout-constraints/) is a brief tutorial on animating autolayout constraint changes. If you setup your constraints properly you should be able to do something as simple as:

```
myLabel.sizeToFit()
```

and the requested changes will happen.

> Do I need to import a library?

No external libraries are needed. You can however look [here](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/) to see if something similar exist.

Comment: Thanks! I will try these tutorials.